# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am getting the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare(), 1 passed in /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-content/plugins/ocarina-tabs/ocarina-tabs.php on line 635 and exactly 2 expected in /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1222 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-content/plugins/ocarina-tabs/ocarina-tabs.php(635): wpdb->prepare('\r\n\t\tSELECT DIST...') #1 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): octab_autocomplete_config('') #2 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-admin/admin-header.php(142): do_action('admin_head') #5 /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-admin/plugins.php(448): require_once('/home/admin/pub...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/admin/public_html/ocarinatab.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1222

The line in question is the second one below :

```html
$artists_array = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = 'octab_artist'"
 ));
```

I cannot seem to find wp-db.php to know what it is missing. Does anyone know specifically what is missing or how to quick-fix this to work again? It worked well prior to some upgrades, but it appears wp-db has checked requirements to need another input?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ . You should first read this. there is full answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $artists_array = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT DISTINCT meta_value  FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
  WHERE meta_key = %s",'octab_artist'
));
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I've also tried using ', $myID' which worked as well. It looks as though it wants an extra field regardless of the field. Thank you.